# how to split a vector on a delimiter

Tags: clojure

I have a vector that contains numbers.
The structure of the vector is the following:

1. items of arbitrary length
2. a separator [0 0 0 0 0] (0 repeated 5 times) between the items

I want to write a function `split` that retrieves the list of the items (without the separator): It is similar to [string/split](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.string/split).

For instance:

```
(split [123 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 199])
; => [[123 0 1] [1 1] [1 0 1] [0 0 1 199]]
```

**Remark: the code has to be effective as the length of the vector is around 1 million.**

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is the list of items: `[[1 0] [0 1]]` feasible? What is the vector that splits into it?

Comment: @Thumbnail I need the same behaviour as [string/split](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.string/split).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here:

```
(defn the-split [coll] 
  (let [part   (partition-by identity coll)
        ppart  (partition-by #(= [0 0 0 0 0] %) part)
        almost (map #(apply concat %) ppart)]
    (filter (partial not= [0 0 0 0 0]) almost)))


(the-split [123 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 199])
=> ((123 0 1) (1 1) (1 0 1) (1 199))
```

Comment: Nice, but this fails if `0` starts or ends a valid data block: `(the-split [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 2]) ;=> ((0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 2))`. However, the grammar is ambiguous as to whether `((0 1) (0 2))` or `((0 1 0) (2))` would be correct.

Comment: @A. Webb Exactly. If we have 6 or more zeros aligned, should the separator be the first 5 zeros or the last 5 zeros? Maybe the author of the question have a clue...

Comment: @A.Webb Not only is the grammar ambiguous, it also, so far as I can see, does not encode all possible lists of items: I can contrive *no* vector that decodes into `[[1 0] [0 1]]`, for instance. I have asked OP about this.

Comment: @A.Webb  I need the same behaviour as [string/split](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.string/split).

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach -- with the `[0 0 0 0 0]` separator hardwired, but straightforward to generalize:

```
(defn split5z [xs]
  (let [delim [0 0 0 0 0]
        step (fn step [xs seg]
               (lazy-seq
                (if-let [xs (seq xs)]
                  (let [window (take 5 xs)]
                    (if (= window delim)
                      (cons seg (step (drop 5 xs) []))
                      (step (rest xs) (conj seg (first xs)))))
                  (list seg))))]
    (step xs [])))
```

Applying it to your sample input:

```
(split5z [123 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 199])
;= ([123 0 1] [1 1] [1 0 1] [1 199])
```

Wrap in `vec` if you'd like the output to be a vector rather than a seq of vectors.

Another approach -- this time eagerly consuming the input with `loop`/`recur`:

```
(defn split5z [sep xs]
  (let [scnt (count sep)]
    (loop [xs  (seq xs)
           out []
           seg []]
      (if xs
        (if (= (take scnt xs) sep)
          (recur (nthnext xs scnt)
                 (conj out seg)
                 [])
          (recur (next xs)
                 out
                 (conj seg (first xs))))
        (if (seq seg)
          (conj out seg)
          seg)))))
```

At the REPL:

```
(split5z [0 0 0 0 0]
         [123 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 199])
;= [[123 0 1] [1 1] [1 0 1] [1 199]]
```

Answer (score 1):

A lazy solution:

```
(defn split [v]
  (let [delim (repeat 5 0)
        i (->> v (partition 5 1) (take-while #(not= delim %)) count)]
    (if (zero? i) [v] (lazy-seq (cons (subvec v 0 i)
                                      (split (subvec v (+ i 5))))))))
```

For example

```
(split [123 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 199])
; ([123 0 1] [1 1] [1 0 1] [0 0 1 199])
```